# Stop Another Video when Playing Current Video Viewpager 2 and Exoplayer

Tags: android, android-viewpager, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x, android-viewpager2

I'm workig on Swipable Video Player using `ViewPager 2` and `Exoplayer 2`. In my code everything is working fine and Video is playing when showing to current visible view of ViewPager. Big problem is when I swipe quickly to 3 - 4 videos. All above videos playing simultaneously (Video and Audio in background)

**Currently What I'm facing problem is that**

**1.** All videos playing simultaneously after quick swipe to 3 - 4 videos

**2.** Video is not getting played when Swipe to previous video

**3.** 2 videos are getting played (current and next) when hold viewPager for swipe.

This is my Activity Class code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements VideoAdapter.VideoClickListener {
    private ArrayList<String> video;
    private ViewPager2 viewPager;
    private int currentVideoIndex = -1;
    private boolean isUserScrolling = false;
    String acc = CLOUD_ID;
    VideoAdapter videoAdapter;
    private VideoAdapter.VideoViewHolder previousViewHolder;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        
        video = new ArrayList<>();
        video.add("https://"+acc+".r2.dev/media/Video12.mp4");
        video.add("https://"+acc+".r2.dev/media/Video13.mp4");
        video.add("https://"+acc+".r2.dev/media/Video10.mp4");
        video.add("https://"+acc+".r2.dev/media/Video6.mp4");
        video.add("https://"+acc+".r2.dev/media/Video9.mp4");
        video.add("https://"+acc+".r2.dev/media/Video4.mp4");

        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        videoAdapter = new VideoAdapter(this,viewPager);
        videoAdapter.setVideo(video);
        videoAdapter.setContext(this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(videoAdapter);


        viewPager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                if (!isUserScrolling) {
                    currentVideoIndex = position;
                    playVideo(position);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                isUserScrolling = state == ViewPager2.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING;
                if (!isUserScrolling && currentVideoIndex != -1) {
                    playVideo(currentVideoIndex);
                }
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onVideoClicked(int position) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(position, false);
    }

    private void playVideo(int position) {
        if (video.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }

        RecyclerView recyclerView = viewPager.getChildAt(0) instanceof RecyclerView ? (RecyclerView) viewPager.getChildAt(0) : null;
        if (recyclerView == null) {
            return;
        }

        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position);
        if (viewHolder instanceof VideoAdapter.VideoViewHolder) {
            VideoAdapter.VideoViewHolder videoViewHolder = (VideoAdapter.VideoViewHolder) viewHolder;
            videoViewHolder.playVideo();

            // Stop playback in the previous ViewHolder if it exists
            if (previousViewHolder != null && previousViewHolder != videoViewHolder) {
                previousViewHolder.stopVideo();
            }

            // Set the current ViewHolder as the previous ViewHolder
            previousViewHolder = videoViewHolder;
        }
    }

}
```

And this is My Adapter Class Code:

```
public class VideoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VideoAdapter.VideoViewHolder> {
    private List<String> video;
    Context context;
    private VideoClickListener videoClickListener;
    ViewPager2 viewPager;

    public VideoAdapter(VideoClickListener videoClickListener, ViewPager2 viewPager) {
        this.videoClickListener = videoClickListener;
        this.viewPager = viewPager;
        video = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void setContext(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    public void setVideo(List<String> video) {
        this.video = video;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public VideoViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_video, parent, false);
        return new VideoViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(VideoViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") int position) {
        holder.bindVideo(position);
    }

    public interface VideoClickListener {
        void onVideoClicked(int position);
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return video.size();
    }

    class VideoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView thumbnail;
        PlayerView playerView;
        ExoPlayer player;

        VideoViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            thumbnail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
            playerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.playerView);
        }

        void bindVideo(int position) {
            
            MediaItem mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(Uri.parse(video.get(position)));

            if (player == null) {
                player = new ExoPlayer.Builder(itemView.getContext()).build();
                playerView.setPlayer(player);
                player.setMediaItem(mediaItem);
                player.prepare();
            } else {
                if (player.isPlaying()) {
                    player.stop();
                }
                player.clearMediaItems();
                player.setMediaItem(mediaItem);
                player.prepare();
            }

            itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                videoClickListener.onVideoClicked(getAdapterPosition());
            });
        }

        void playVideo() {
            if (player != null && !player.isPlaying()) {
                player.play();
            }
        }

        void stopVideo() {
            if (player != null && player.isPlaying()) {
                player.stop();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

I can add XML code of both if needed.

Please give a time to resolve this isse. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

add OnPageChangeCallback implementation, then in onPageScrollStateChanged method, if state !=2 call stop player method.